# throwing a warning and treating a error like declared formal parameter list different from definition

Tags: c, visual-studio

```c
void test_leave_aoabound_Responder(uint8_t ranging_data_ntf, uint8_t Angle)
{
    LOG_W(
        "**************************************************************************************************************"
        "************");
    LOG_W(
        "Ensure \"USE_NAKED_BOARD\" is set to 0 in  boards/Host/Rhodes4/UWB_DeviceConfig.h before you run this test on "
        "V3 Demonstator");
    //LOG_W(
      //  "**************************************************************************************************************");

    uint8_t antennaeConfigurationRx[] = {
        kUWBAntCfgRxMode_AoA_Mode, /* Mode of Operation */
        0x02,                      /* size of configuration data */
        0x01,                      /* RX Pair H ID */
        0x02,                      /* RX Pair V ID */
    };
    uint8_t rangedataboundAoA1[] = {0x00, 0xd3, 0x00, 0x2d, 0x00, 0xd3, 0x00, 0x2d};
    uint8_t rangedataboundAoA2[] = {0x00, 0xfb, 0x00, 0x05, 0x00, 0xfb, 0x00, 0x05};
    tUWBAPI_STATUS status = UWBAPI_STATUS_FAILED;
    if (Angle == AZ_10_10_EL_10_10) {
        Value1(rangedataboundAoA2);
        gTestSuiteCtx.expected_success_count = 0;
    }
    else if (Angle == AZ_90_90_EL_90_90) {
        Value1(rangedataboundAoA1);
        gTestSuiteCtx.expected_success_count = 10;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't describe what a warning was. Copy&paste the exact message into the question. That includes the exact position where it was shown and what functions is affected. Also your code fragment is not even a complete function. We cannot put it into compiler and see what happens. Please edit your question to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Without enough information I would guess that you have some declaration of `test_leave_aoabound_Responder` earlier in the code, probably in a header, that does not have the same signature.